# Not getting the exact data when reversing FFT

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, fft, kissfft

Okay, what I'm trying to achieve is simple. Apply FFT on some random data and then apply the reverse algorithm on the output to get back the input. I'm using `kissFFT` library for this.

Code:

```
const int fft_siz = 512;
const int inverse = 1;

kiss_fft_cpx* in = (kiss_fft_cpx*)malloc(sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx) * fft_siz);
kiss_fft_cpx* out = (kiss_fft_cpx*)malloc(sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx) * fft_siz);
kiss_fft_cpx* rec = (kiss_fft_cpx*)malloc(sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx) * fft_siz);
kiss_fft_cfg cfg = kiss_fft_alloc(fft_siz, !inverse, NULL, NULL);
kiss_fft_cfg icfg = kiss_fft_alloc(fft_siz, inverse, NULL, NULL);

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < fft_siz; i++)
{
    in[i].r = rand() % 256;
    in[i].i = rand() % 256;
}

kiss_fft(cfg, in, out);

// scaling
for(int i = 0; i < fft_siz; i++)
{
    out[i].r /= fft_siz;
    out[i].i /= fft_siz;
}

kiss_fft(icfg, out, rec);

unsigned int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < fft_siz; i++)
    if(in[i].r != rec[i].r)
    {
        count++;
        printf( "in[%3d].r does not match rec[%3d].r :: %3d :: %f\n",
                i, i, count, in[i].r - rec[i].r);
    }
    else if(in[i].i != rec[i].i)
    {
        count++;
        printf( "in[%3d].i does not match rec[%3d].i :: %3d :: %f\n",
                i, i, count, in[i].i - rec[i].i);
    }

free(in);
free(out);
free(rec);
free(cfg);
free(icfg);

kiss_fft_cleanup();
```

Output:

```
in[  0]:     71.000000       85.000000 -- out[  0]:    127.095703      124.541016
in[  1]:    248.000000       27.000000 -- out[  1]:     -7.083314        0.072701
in[  2]:     64.000000       18.000000 -- out[  2]:     -3.770610        2.682554
in[  3]:      6.000000       96.000000 -- out[  3]:     -7.929140       -2.897723
in[  4]:     98.000000       23.000000 -- out[  4]:     -0.719621       -5.854260
in[  5]:    250.000000      188.000000 -- out[  5]:      0.397226       -1.248124
in[  6]:    231.000000        3.000000 -- out[  6]:     -7.934285       -2.367196
in[  7]:      6.000000      105.000000 -- out[  7]:     -0.317480       -2.955601
in[  8]:    172.000000      143.000000 -- out[  8]:     -4.236186        3.911616
in[  9]:     16.000000      134.000000 -- out[  9]:     -0.162577       -5.353521
in[ 10]:    230.000000      112.000000 -- out[ 10]:     -4.703711        7.791993
in[ 11]:      5.000000       26.000000 -- out[ 11]:     -2.636305        0.188381
in[ 12]:     16.000000      127.000000 -- out[ 12]:      1.137413        4.576081
in[ 13]:    112.000000       86.000000 -- out[ 13]:      0.978051       -0.408992
in[ 14]:     40.000000       23.000000 -- out[ 14]:      5.231920       -2.347566
in[ 15]:     75.000000       26.000000 -- out[ 15]:      0.009981       -2.091559

note                                ::count::difference
--------------------------------------------------------
in[  1].r does not match rec[  1].r ::   1 :: -0.000031
in[  3].r does not match rec[  3].r ::   2 :: -0.000015
in[  4].i does not match rec[  4].i ::   3 :: -0.000004
in[  6].i does not match rec[  6].i ::   4 :: -0.000008
in[  7].r does not match rec[  7].r ::   5 :: -0.000002
in[  9].r does not match rec[  9].r ::   6 :: -0.000015
in[ 11].r does not match rec[ 11].r ::   7 :: -0.000015
in[ 12].r does not match rec[ 12].r ::   8 :: -0.000015
in[ 13].i does not match rec[ 13].i ::   9 :: -0.000008
in[ 14].i does not match rec[ 14].i ::  10 :: 0.000008
in[ 15].r does not match rec[ 15].r ::  11 :: -0.000015
```

[Debug](http://m.uploadedit.com/b017/1372556049144.txt). If you go to the bottom, you'll see that there's 317 mismatches. I'm also outputting the difference between values i.e. `(in[].r - rec[].r)` or `(in[].i - rec[].i)`.

What I'm showing next is the input data where white dots represent the real part and red dots the imaginary part.

[image]

This is the output data of FFT represented in purple along with the **reconstructed** data in white and red.

[image]

[image]

Notice the small difference? I'm guessing this is related to floating point precision.
How can I overcome this problem to get the exact same input data that I used FFT on ?

### Edit:

I noticed that the range off error in my case is something like ]0 , 0.002]. So as a workaround, I rounded the reconstructed data and got a good result. But still... This only works if the fractional part of my numbers is 0.0.

Answer (score 3):

You're guess is correct; floats have a limited precision, and some of the input precision will be lost in the process. If you want the exact input, you'll need some sort of arbitrary-precision floating-point library (for example, the [GNU MP library](http://gmplib.org/)).

Comment: meh, it would be a pain to modify a library using another one knowing that I didn't wrote neither of them.

Comment: An arbitrary-precision library is insufficient to provide exact results. Many of the coefficients used in the FFT are irrational (more than that, transcendental). So they are not exactly representable in any finite precision or base. More precision can only reduce error, not eliminate it. However, there is generally no reason for exact results in an FFT anyway. Any data obtained from the real world (e.g., via microphone) has measurement errors, so any processing on it must tolerate errors. It is only a question of how much, keeping the noise below an acceptable level.

Comment: So, losing some accuracy is inevitable ?!

Comment: Well, if you absolutely **must** have exact results, you can use some sort of symbolic math library